# How to change 1,000,000.00 into 1.000.000,00 with ASP classic?

Tags: asp-classic, numbers, format

I want to change number 1,000,000.00 into 1.000.000,00 with ASP classic. Please help

```
a=1000000
response.write formatnumber(a,0)
```

It shows

```
1,000,000
```

Comment: I don't write tag asp.net , maybe it's edited by someone. ASP Classic" (with VBA). I try to use asp classic but when i submit it show can't use asp classic tag. What i should do?

Comment: I added `asp-classic` as a tag for you (and removed `asp.net`)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this because the delimiter used depends on the [regional settings](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140205/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/031401-1.shtml) of the Computer. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_formatnumber.asp) for more on the `FormatNumber` function and its use.

There is a round-about way. You can have the decimal points and turn off grouping like this:

```
a=1000000
response.write(FormatNumber(a,2,,,0))
```

You can then insert your preferred delimiter using your own function: see this [example](https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8175&lngWId=4).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping me.

I add strreverse() function to your example Public Function

```
Public Function Format(sValue, sMask)
    Dim iPlaceHolder
    Dim sTempValue
    Dim sResult

    sTempValue = CStr(strreverse(sValue))
    sResult = sMask
    Do Until InStr(sResult, "#") = 0
        iPlaceHolder = InStr(sResult, "#")
        sResult = Replace(sResult, "#", Left(sTempValue, 1), 1, 1)
        sTempValue = Mid(sTempValue, 2)
        If Len(sTempValue) = 0 Then sResult = Left(sResult, iPlaceHolder)
    Loop
    Format = strreverse(sResult)
End Function
```

response.write format(a, "###.###.###.###.###")&",00"

output: 1.000.000,00

Comment: That's good. You can mark it as answer if it solved your problem